# What logic rule is used to show $(p \lor q) \land (p)=p~$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

> What logic rule is used to show: $(p \vee q) \wedge (p)=p~$?

This is obvious, because if p is true the whole expression is true, and if p is false, the whole expression is false, but I'm not sure which logic rule is used to draw this conclusion.

Comment: please use `\land` for $\land$ and `\lor` for $\lor$.

Comment: You could make a truth table to prove it, which you basically have written in text.

Comment: Various rules might be invoked.  What "rules" do you have to work with?

Comment: the rules we have so far are: Identities: $p \lor F = p$, $p\land T = P$, $p\lor T=T$, $p \land F = F$; commutative laws; associative laws; distributive laws; complement laws $p \land ~p=F$, $p \lor ~p=T$; Idempotent; Demorgan's; and double Negation

Comment: You need to put `$...$` around your formula, like `$p \lor q$` for $p \lor q$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show this with Boolean algebra as follows:
$$
(p \vee q)\wedge p = (p \vee q)\wedge (p\vee F) = p \vee (q \wedge F) = p \vee F = p
$$
If we have $\cdot$ for $\wedge$ and $+$ for $\vee$, then here's what this looks like:
$$
(p+q)p = (p+q)(p+0) = p+q0 = p+0 = p
$$
To prove this, I am using the "distributive laws" of and/or.  That is,

- $p \wedge(q \vee r) = (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r)$
- $p \vee(q \wedge r) = (p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee r)$

Answer (score 1):

The statement to be proved is that
$$p \equiv p \land (p \lor q),$$
which from the definition of the biconditional can be broken into 2 statements
\begin{equation} \label{1} \tag{1}  p \rightarrow  p \land (p \lor q) \end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} \label{2} \tag{2} p \land (p \lor q) \rightarrow p. \end{equation}

$\ref{2} \ $ follows very simply, we just use the rule of simplification or conjunction elimination to conclude $p$ immediately.

For $ \ \ref{1} \ $ we start with $p$ and use addition or disjunction introduction to write $p \lor q$, and then combine the 2 expressions using conjunction introduction to conclude $ p \land (p \lor q)$